# My node js code has no effect on the keyword "require"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest

I am beginner studying node.js, REST API and MongoDB by following some online resources. I tried to use the keyword "require" in my following code so that the users are not allowed to input blank value:

ninjas.js (create schema and models)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//create Schema and model
const NinjaSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        require: [true,'Name field is required']
    },
    rank:{
        type: String,
        require: [true,'This field is required']
    },
    available:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        require: [true,'This field is required']
    }
    //add in geo loction
});

const Ninja = mongoose.model('hi ninja',NinjaSchema);

module.exports = Ninja;
```

Below is the code handling the API:

api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const Ninja = require('../models/ninjas');
const router = express.Router();

//get a list of ninjas from the database
router.get('/ninjas',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send({type: 'GET'});
})

//add a new ninjas to the database
router.post('/ninjas',(req,res,next)=>{
    //create a Ninja object and save it to DB
    Ninja.create(req.body).then((ninja) => {
        res.send(ninja)
    }).catch(next);
})

//update a ninjas in the database
router.put('/ninjas/:id',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send({type: 'PUT'});
})

//delete a ninjas from the database
router.delete('/ninjas/:id',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.send({type: 'DELETE'});
})

module.exports = router;
```

Below is the main program:

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//set up express app
const app = express();

//connect to mondodb
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/ninjago",{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//initialize routes
app.use('/api',require('./routes/api'));

//error handling middleware
app.use((err,req,res,next) => {
    //console.log(err);
    res.status(422).send({error: err.message});
});

//listen for requests
app.listen(process.env.port || 4000,() => {
    console.log('now listening for requests');
});
```

However, when I tried to use POSTMAN to test the API, I found that even I did not some parameter, the system would still return a successful message.
[image]

May I know if there is something wrong or missing in my code causing the "require" keyword not working? Thank you so much!

Hon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `require` with the keyword `required` in your schema

```
const NinjaSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: [true,'Name field is required']
    },
    rank:{
        type: String,
        required: [true,'This field is required']
    },
    available:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        required: [true,'This field is required']
    }
    //add in geo loction
});
```

See [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#validation) for reference.

Comment: Thank you so much Kartik! Sorry for my stupid typo mistake!